# Don't have main class or program arguments to add configuration in IntelliJ Idea on Linux

Tags: java, intellij-idea, installation, configuration

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA by Jetbrains community edition on my linux device. But to run my first program I need to add configuration (I don't have much idea about Java but I have used PyCharm in the past and add configuration panel is quite similar to add interpreter thing there). I don't know any configuration setting, I think it is supposed to automatically load configuration settings, a default one for the first time, but it doesn't. If I have to create a main class first then I don't what code to write in that. In every installation guide, they just assume that a configuration is already there. In documentations etc. they tell how to edit those fields and the way main class decides what to find in any program to execute. But I couldn't add a configuration to start executing any program.

I need help with the highlighted fields in the following screenshot

[image]

This guide from jetbrains.com didn't help:
[image]

I'm not sure but I get that first I have to create something like main.java and then add it in the main class field but I'm completely clueless about program arguments. Environment variables are optional I guess.

Please help. Thank You

**Edit:** Here's the file which I'm trying to use for main class field in the configuration.

```
public class Lbasic1 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println("I make mistakes");
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** I don't get any option as Run Lbasic1.main() anywhere. Here is the screenshot of IDE
[image]

Comment: Create any class with a `public static void main(String[] args) {}` method and use that class as a main class. Inside that `main` method put whatever logic you need as your program. The program arguments and environment variables are optional. If you have some repo with your specific source code I probably could help better.

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://github.com/lealceldeiro/interview-questions/blob/f2f04df410e5fcfbb55cc54801e5bf289841fd43/src/main/java/Main.java#L31

Comment: @lealceldeiro I created a java class (which is actually the first program I wanted to execute) and that has this `public static void main(String[] args) {}` method but when I go to Project (to choose the main class file) and select this file (named Lbasic.java), the "ok" button gets grayed out.

Comment: What if you right click the class on the left panel (the navigator) and choose "Run <Class>.main" where main the the actual name of your class (like `Main`, `Program` or whatever you called it)?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Please check edit 2. I have attached a screenshot

Comment: Try including the class **inside** the *src* folder ... additionally it should be good to have inside a package (still inside the src folder)

Comment: It's clear that you wish to learn Java. That's all good and that's what you should be doing. Instead you're asking questions about how to use IntelliJ. Now, the particular questions you've asked, you *wouldn't have needed* to ask if you'd learned the Java basics first. So you've given yourself a *double* learning curve - learning Java and learning IntelliJ and you won't know what's Java knowledge and what's particular to IntelliJ.

Comment: Even worse, using an IDE will hide knowledge of certain Java essentials such as the classpath and packages which you must be fluent in to do Java properly. Do yourself a favour - get a good tutorial and learn the basics with a text editor and the Java compiler alone. You can always use an IDE later. Personally I rarely use one and I've been doing Java since it was invented/

Comment: @g00se Yeah, what you are saying is right. Also, I wanted to tell that the book I am currently reading is Herbert Schlidt's Java- a beginner's guide and this book actually expect the readers to do the same as you're doing. It doesn't have any installation guide and absolutely nothing for IDE. I've actually run a few basic programs using java compiler and text editor. I just wanted to try using an IDE, so I installed one on my linux device. Perhaps it was too early for me to use IntelliJ but I have seen many books teaching java with an IDE only from the complete basics. So I did what..

Comment: ....I was not supposed to do perhaps. And as per your advice I'll definitely do myself the favour- not to use IDE until I learn most part of Java programming, especially theory so that I don't have to ask absurd/silly questions like these.

Comment: Good plan. I use gvim personally for small stuff